ktor api call with two expected outcomes
im building a mock isuranceApp and in the otp verification step we should expect two outcomes
see i sent a otp request:
{
phoneNumber = "+101234123412",
secretKey = "abc"
}

and now the user might be a registered user in which case the response will be:
{
userId = "000",
token = "abc101"
}

and if its not a registered user we get this as response:
{
message = "code is correct",
opCode = "xxx"
}

well as you see there is two expected out comes and i dont know how to handle this with my half copy pasted architecture:
ill show you the proccess from the viewModel to my httpClientFactory
viewModel:
class OTPViewModel(
    private val repository: AuthRepository
): ViewModel() {

    private fun verify() {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            state = state.copy(isLoggingIn = true)

            val result = repository.loginOTP(
                otpCode = state.otpCode.text.toString().trim()
            )

            state = state.copy(isLoggingIn = false)

            when(result) {
                is Result.Error -> {
                    if (result.error == DataError.Network.CONFLICT) {


                    } else {
                        eventChannel.send(OTPEvent.Error(result.error.asUiText()))
                    }
                }
                // handle the secreteKey mechanism in sessionStorage
                is Result.Success -> {

                }
            }
        }
    }

}

result class:
sealed interface Result<out D, out E: Error> {

     data class  Success<out D>(val data: D): Result<D, Nothing>
     data class  Error<out E: com.example.core.domain.util.Error>(val error: E): Result<Nothing, E>
}

inline fun <T, E: Error, R> Result<T, E>.map(map: (T) -> R): Result<R, E> {
     return when(this) {
          is Result.Error -> Result.Error(error)
          is Result.Success -> Result.Success(map(data))
     }
}

fun <T, E: Error> Result<T, E>.asEmptyResult(): EmptyResult<E> {
     return map {  }
}

typealias EmptyResult<E> = Result<Unit, E>

authRepository:
class AuthRepositoryImpl(
    private val httpClient: HttpClient,
    val sessionStorage: SessionStorage
): AuthRepository {
    override suspend fun loginPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String): EmptyResult<DataError.Network> {
        val result =  httpClient.post<LoginPhoneNumberRequest, LoginPhoneNumberResponse>(
            route = "/req",
            body = LoginPhoneNumberRequest(
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber
            )
        )

        if (result is Result.Success) {
            sessionStorage.setSecretKey(
                secretKey = result.data.secretKey
            )
        }

        return result.asEmptyResult()
    }

    override suspend fun loginOTP(otpCode: String): EmptyResult<DataError.Network> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

httpClient:
suspend inline fun <reified Request, reified Response: Any> HttpClient.post(
    route: String,
    body: Request
): Result<Response, DataError.Network> {

    return safeCall {
        post {
            url(constructRoute(route))
            setBody(body)
        }
    }
}

suspend inline fun <reified T> safeCall(execute: () -> HttpResponse): Result<T, DataError.Network> {
    val response = try {
        execute()
    } catch (e: UnresolvedAddressException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return Result.Error(DataError.Network.NO_INTERNET)
    } catch (e: SerializationException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return Result.Error(DataError.Network.SERIALIZATION)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (e is CancellationException) throw e
        e.printStackTrace()
        return Result.Error(DataError.Network.UNKNOWN)
    }

    return responseToResult(response)
}


suspend inline fun <reified T> responseToResult(response: HttpResponse): Result<T, DataError.Network> {
    return when (response.status.value){
        in 200..299 -> Result.Success(response.body<T>())
        401 -> Result.Error(DataError.Network.UNAUTHORIZED)
        408 -> Result.Error(DataError.Network.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
        409 -> Result.Error(DataError.Network.CONFLICT)
        413 -> Result.Error(DataError.Network.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
        429 -> Result.Error(DataError.Network.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS)
        in 500..599 -> Result.Error(DataError.Network.SERVER_ERROR)
        else -> Result.Error(DataError.Network.UNKNOWN)
    }
}

fun constructRoute(route: String): String {
    return when {
        route.contains(BuildConfig.BASE_URL) -> route
        route.startsWith("/") -> BuildConfig.BASE_URL + route
        else -> BuildConfig.BASE_URL + "/$route"
    }
}

